# Array starts at index 19

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm using a third party lib to make some financial calculations. I'm passing an array with size of 500, and it returns me the same size array with the calculations.

The problem is that the lib uses the 20 first numbers to calculate the moving average, and then it returns an array that starts at index 19:

[image: array]

When I'm inspecting in Webstorm Debugger, it shows that the array starts at index 19.

I need to change these first 19 number to an empty object `{}`. I tried to map it and verifying if it's `null`:

```
      const lowerBands: Values[] = bands.lower.map((l) => {
        if (l === null) {
          return {};
        }
        return { y: l };
      });
```

But when the map function is invoked, it starts at index 19, and the first 19 numbers aren't evaluated.

What's happening with this array, and why can't I manipulate the first 19 index?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Post CODE, not just console.log dumps

Comment: `.map()` (and the other array iteration methods) does not go through empty slots. You can use a regular loop or other stuff to access those

Comment: Weird. Is that the documented behavior of the 3rd party lib?

Comment: Can't you filter out the empty ones?

Comment: @VLAZ you're right. Using a regular for and accessing the index directly solved the problem. Thanks